# How to use refresh_token tousecalendar api after access_token has expired. oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken() is deprecated

Tags: node.js, express, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using `google-api-nodejs-client` to access google calendar apis. I save the `access_token`, `refresh_token`, `expiry_date` to my db.

When user checks for calendar events, I set credentials of my oAuth2Client with values stored in my db.

It works fine till `access_token` expires. After that, I get the following error:

> Missing required parameter: refresh_token

My code is:

```
fn getData(date) {
    //set access_token adnd refresh_token to values taken from db
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
        access_token: 'val from db',
        refresh_token: 'val from db' 
    })
    calendar = google.calendar({
        version: 'v3', 
        auth: oAuth2Client
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh token of google api do not work properly in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286529/refresh-token-of-google-api-do-not-work-properly-in-nodejs)

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(access_token, refresh_token)` to see whether expected values are sent?

Comment: @Mendi refreshAccessToken method is being deprecated

Comment: thank you i was sending wrong refresh token